# Can the quotient set of a permutation equivalence relation be a vector space again?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and consider the equivalence relation $x\sim y\Leftrightarrow \exists \sigma\in\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{R}^N)\,\, x = \sigma(y)$ for some permutation $\sigma$. Let $A = \mathbb{R}^N/\sim$ be the quotient set. Is it possible to define an addition between elements of $A$ (+ inverse and scalar multiplication) such that $A$ becomes a vector space?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^N$ with all entries equal to $1$. Then the map $a\mapsto [au]$ is an injection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^N$. By Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein, we conclude that $|\mathbb{R}^N|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

> This is because $|\mathbb{R}^N|=|\mathbb{R}|$ (assuming $N$ is a positive integer), so $|\mathbb{R}^N/{\sim}|\le|\mathbb{R}^N|=|\mathbb{R}|$

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^N/{\sim}$ be a bijection. Use it to transfer the vector space structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I am not sure how your answer relates to my question, nor do I see why the conclusion $|\mathbb{R}^N| = |\mathbb{R}|$ would be true.

Comment: @w382903 $|\mathbb{R}^2|=|\mathbb{R}|$ (“I see it, but a can't believe to it”, allegedly wrote Cantor to Dedekind; but it's indeed true). I added a couple of other hints.